# put left padded zeros inside string

Tags: r

i want to write a function which takes a character Vector(including numbers) as Input and left pads zeroes to the numbers in it. for example this could be an Input Vector :

```
x<- c("abc124.kk", "77kk-tt", "r5mm")

x
[1] "abc124.kk" "77kk-tt"   "r5mm"
```

each string of the input Vector contains only one Vector but there all in different positions(some are at the end, some in the middle..)

i want the ouput to look like this:

```
"abc124.kk" "077kk-tt"   "r005mm"
```

that means to put as many leading Zeros to the number included in the string so that it has as many Digits as the longest number.
but i want a function who does this for every string Input not only my example(the x Vector).

i already started extracting the numbers and letters and turned the numbers the way i want them  but how  can i put them back together and back on the right Position?

```
my_function<- function(x){

  letters<- str_extract_all(x,"[a-z]+")
  numbers<- str_extract_all(x, "[0-9]+")

  digit_width<-max(nchar(numbers))
  numbers_correct<- str_pad(numbers, width=digit_width, pad="0")

}
```

and what if i have a Vector which includes some strings without numbers? how can i exclude them and get them back without any changes ?
for example if teh Input would be

```
y<- c("12ab", "cd", "ef345")
```

the numbers variable Looks like that:

```
[[1]]
[1] "12"

[[2]]
character(0)
```

in this case i would want that the ouput at the would look like this:

```
 "012ab" "cd"   "ef345"
```

Comment: i tried adding str_replace(x, "[0-9]+", as.character(numbers_correct) but it gets false output in cases when there are strings without numbers as input

Answer (score 2):

```
x <- c("12ab", "cd", "ef345")
s = gsub("\\D", "", x)
n = nchar(s)
max_n = max(n)

sapply(seq_along(x), function(i){
    if (n[i] < max_n) {
        zeroes = paste(rep(0, max_n - n[i]), collapse = "")
        gsub("\\d+", paste0(zeroes, s[i]), x[i])
    } else {
        x[i]
    }
})
#[1] "012ab" "cd"    "ef345"
```

Answer (score 1):

An option would be using `gsubfn` to capture the digits, convert it to `numeric` and then pass it to `sprintf` for formatting

```
library(gsubfn)
gsubfn("([0-9]+)", ~ sprintf("%03d", as.numeric(x)), x)
#[1] "abc124.kk" "077kk-tt"  "r005mm"
```